# stop condition in scipy.integrate.ode for stiff system

Tags: python, scipy, stiffness

I'm using Python scipy.integrate.ode, and I want to stop my integration at a certain condition. So I use the integrator "dopri5" and use the method "set_solout" to specify a function for my stop condition.

Unfortunately, in some cases, the program says my problem is stiff, and exits. (The message is "UserWarning: dopri5: problem is probably stiff (interrupted)"). So I try another integrator. The documentation mentions 3 other integrators ("vode", "zvode" and "lsoda") which might be suitable for stiff problems. (There is also "dop853", but that exits in the same way as "dopri5").

Here's my problem: none of these integrators support the "set_selout" method. So: is there another way to stop any of these integrators on a condition?

EDIT (a few hours later): I got around this with repeated calls of the "integrate" method (with integrator set to "lsoda") with a short time step; and checking my end condition after each call. Ugly, but gets the job done. I'd still like to know if there's a better way to do this.

Comment: The functionality you're after goes by the name "event detection" or "rootfinding".  As far as I can tell, it is not supported in Scipy but is supported by some solvers in [pysundials](http://pysundials.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of a better way to handle this with SciPy since I don't think it has event handling. But if you're willing to venture beyond SciPy, the following software have the capability, either documented as event handling or rootfinding:

- Sundials' CVODE
- MATLAB's `ode23` and `ode15s`
- Julia's DifferentialEquations.jl Sundials wrapper and Rosenbrock methods
- Mathematica's NDSolve

Comment: Thanks. My hack works for now, but if I return to the problem, I'll use Julia or Matlab. (Probably Julia, which I kind of like).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to stick to the Python scientific family, you could opt for [Assimulo](http://www.jmodelica.org/assimulo). Assimulo is a wrapper around a lot of ODE integrators, providing a common interface. If you happen to be running on Windows, you can find wheels at [Christoph Gohlke's page](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#assimulo).

Assimulo allows to handle state events to allow for discontinuities in the RHS function of your ODE but you can use them also to stop the iteration when a certain condition is fulfilled.

The procedure is to define a function 'state_events' that analyzes whether an event took place and a second function 'handle_event' to act accordingly (changing the state equations, changing the variables, stopping the iteration, ...).

The example in the Assimulo package is a pendulum that hits a wall. When it hits the wall, the state changes in the sense that the direction should be reversed and some energy should be lost.

I modified the example that comes with Assimulo, using a simple exponential decay problem where I asked to stop the integration when the concentration of the species drops below a threshold value. See the code below.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python 
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import numpy as N
import pylab as P
from assimulo.problem import Explicit_Problem
from assimulo.solvers.sundials import CVode
from assimulo.exception import TerminateSimulation


def run_example():

    def decay(t,y):

        yd_0 = -0.5*y[0]

        return N.array([yd_0])

    def state_events(t,y,sw):
        """
        This is our function that keep track of our events, when the sign
        of any of the events has changed, we have an event.
        """

        return N.array([y[0]-50.0])


    def handle_event(solver, event_info):
        """
        Event handling. This functions is called when Assimulo finds an event as
        specified by the event functions.
        """
        state_info = event_info[0] #We are only interested in state events info

        if state_info[0] != 0: #Check if the first event function have been triggered
            raise TerminateSimulation


    #Initial values
    y0 = [100.0] #Initial states
    t0 = 0.0             #Initial time

    #Create an Assimulo Problem
    mod = Explicit_Problem(decay, y0, t0)

    mod.state_events = state_events #Sets the state events to the problem
    mod.handle_event = handle_event #Sets the event handling to the problem
    mod.name = 'Simple decay'   #Sets the name of the problem

    #Create an Assimulo solver (CVode)
    sim = CVode(mod)

    #Specifies options 
    sim.discr = 'BDF'     #Sets the discretization method
    sim.iter = 'Newton' #Sets the iteration method
    sim.rtol = 1.e-8        #Sets the relative tolerance
    sim.atol = 1.e-6        #Sets the absolute tolerance

    #Simulation
    ncp = 200     #Number of communication points
    tfinal = 10.0 #Final time

    t,y = sim.simulate(tfinal, ncp) #Simulate

    #Print event information
    sim.print_event_data()

    #Plot
    P.plot(t,y)
    P.show()

if __name__=='__main__':
    run_example()
```

Answer (score 0):

**Event detection in python:**

The solution could be 
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.solve_ivp.html

From the documentation: ‘RK45’ or ‘RK23’ method for non-stiff problems and ‘Radau’ or ‘BDF’ for stiff problems.